# Failed to scan device on Ubuntu with Python BLE library

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I am trying to use Python BLE library to connect my BLE device on both IOS and Ubuntu, now it's working well on IOS, but when it always fails when the same script is executed on Ubuntu when the call "adapter.start_scan" is called:

```
adapter.start_scan()
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/Adafruit_BluefruitLE/bluez_dbus/adapter.py", line 69, in start_scan
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
**keywords)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.bluez.Error.InProgress: Operation already in progress
```

I searched everywhere, but still can't get solution. Can anyone help me on this?